# Java: how to find all references to a specific class instance

Tags: java, debugging

I have a Java application where a specific object is the principal reason of RAM occupation, this is ok. Application logic has to drop this object instance and create a new one. I suspect old instance is kept alive by some reference.

Is there a way to list all references of a specific class instance using Eclipse debug or anything else?

Comment: use jvisualvm  if you want to monitor the the objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Eclipse Memory Analyzer plugin (org.eclipse.mat.feature.feature.group):

- Run your application to the point where you suspect the memory leak
- Open the Memory Analysis perspective in Eclipse
- Click "Acquire Heap Dump" button in toolbar

  - Eclipse will need enough memory to process it, usually about the same amount as the application analyzed - you might need to change `eclispe.ini` to add more memory (if you don't have enough RAM you may instead create the memory dump using jvisualvm then close the app and start eclipse with increased `-Xmx`)
- Once the dump loads, you can browse it to identify the leak source (I don't recall details, but roughly - browse to your class, right click, view objects with incoming references)